# A boy hit by lightning is sent to another universe

Tags: story-identification, books

My girlfriend read a book when she was a kid about a boy who was hit by lightning and sent to a different universe or planet or something (her memory is fuzzy on the details).

That's all she can remember.

Does anyone have any idea of the possible title of this book?

Comment: When did she read it, was it a new book at the time, was it in English?

Comment: Reminds me of the Den short from Heavy Metal. But that was the Loknar, not lightning.

Answer (score 4):

Taking a wild shot at this, my guess based on the fuzzy details would be "[Fireball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fireball_%28novel%29)" by John Christopher.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how recently she was a kid, it could be [The Transal Saga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Transall_Saga) by Gary Paulson.  It's a beam of light, not lightning though.

Answer (score 1):

"Through the Lightning Gate" by Jim Eldridge could be possibility:
Synopsis from the back cover:

> Meet Freddy A. Kennedy - alias Freak. He's seventeen and pretty cool
> with it - but nothing could have prepared him for being zapped through
> the lighting gate... into a world where tribes of lizard-creatures and
> snarling dog-people prowl the streets night and day.
>
> Enter Eon, the lion woman. She's the only one Freak meets who doesn't
> try to tear him limb from limb - she even helps him understand what's
> going on. So when Eon disappears, captured by the evil warlord Angel,
> Freak plans a rescue mission.